# How to show progress on a progress bar (Retrofit Download)

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, retrofit, android-progressbar

I'm using Retrofit to download a file from the internet, and I want to do a progress bar that show the progress of the download, but I'm having problems
doing that, I was able to do a notification (is not perfect) but is working at some point.....but is like an infinity progress bar that doesn't show the progress of the download.
How can I show the progress on the progress bar?

```
private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body, String fileName) {
    try {
        final int progressMax = 463451606;

        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, activityIntent, 0);
        final NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_2_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_cloud_download_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("Descargando")
            .setContentText("Archivo descargando")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setProgress(progressMax, 0, true);

        notificationManager.notify(2, notification.build());

        // todo change the file location/name according to your needs
        File futureStudioIconFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName);

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];
            final long fileSize = body.contentLength();
            long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

            inputStream = body.byteStream();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile);

            while (true) {
                int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                fileSizeDownloaded += read;
                Log.e(TAG, "Archivo " + fileSizeDownloaded + " de " + fileSize);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                        for (int fileSizeDownloaded = 0; fileSize <= progressMax; fileSizeDownloaded++) {

                        }
                        notification.setContentText("Completado")
                            .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                            .setOngoing(false);
                        notificationManager.notify(2, notification.build());


                    }
                }).start();


            }

            outputStream.flush();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }

            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using AsyncTask ?

Answer (score 2):

The OkHttp recipes on Github have an example of how to do this. https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/Progress.java